GoRouter: what is the event path? Do redirects get a redirect check at their target?
If I am to use GoRoute.redirect to control access (e.g. with user rights per page), I need to understand how a redirect result go through its target route, specifically if it then processes through the target's redirect function
Also, I want to confirm that the original state (with the parameters) arrives at the redirected target
And I want to find out exactly what happens when my app "gets" a link from the OS. Do I need to add a handler for an event? Does it trigger the router to change pages (even if my user is in the middle of something important)?
Please help me find a flowchart or DFD for this
Cheers
